# Why can Ten-Tails jinchuriki stop the reincarnation of Edo Tensei ninja?

Tags: naruto

In one of *Naruto*'s episode, Obito ―after becoming a Ten-Tails' jinchuriki― was able to stop a reincarnated (Edo Tensei) ninja (4th and 2nd Hokage) from recreating its body once it was destroyed.

What's the special thing that allows a Ten-Tails' jinchuriki to do so?

Answer (score 3):

It is called [Gudoudama or Truth-seeking ball](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Truth-Seeking_Ball) which was gained by Obito after being Ten Tailed Jinchuriki.

> Truth-Seeking Balls are hand-sized orbs of black chakra that users can use to alter its shape to serve for a variety of purposes.
>
> When one awakens Six Paths Senjutsu, Truth-Seeking Balls appear and float behind their back. This can be done by becoming the jinchūriki of the Ten-Tails or by entering Six Paths Sage Mode.

And stated in its [usage](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Truth-Seeking_Ball#Usage)

> Truth-Seeking Balls are composed of all five basic natures, in a way similar to yet surpassing kekkei genkai and kekkei touta. If imbued with Yin–Yang Release, they can be used to neutralise ninjutsu and by extension become impervious to it; this negates the regenerative qualities of the Impure World Reincarnation, making it possible to kill or permanently damage those who have been reincarnated.